# How to rename a directory starting with - and space in between?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

The folder was renamed to '-Cadence NDA Extension- Signed 10.2.17.pdf' by mistake and now am not able perform anything on the folder. How to rename it to dicarta? I am trying this in UNIX Shell Script.

Comment: The usual trick is to prefix the name with `./`, and use quotes to avoid spltting on spaces, so use `mv "./-Cadence NDA Extension- Signed 10.2.17.pdf" whataver`

Comment: I am not able to navigate to a folder in winscp. But I am able to see the folder from putty and I can see ERR and ORA inside the folder. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: This seems like a different question. @xenoid would you like to answer this one?

Comment: What do you mean by not able to navigate to a folder in winscp? Is your session open? Is that related to a specific folder? And you can access that very folder using Putty? Are you sure you're using the same credentials logging in?

Comment: Yes to a specific folder. I can access the folder in Putty, but not from WinSCP. Also in putty I see ERR, ORA  in that particular folder. That is weird.

Comment: Below is the error Unexpected directory listing line '   '.
Invalid rights description '  '

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mv -- -Cadence\ NDA\ Extension-\ Signed\ 10.2.17.pdf some-other-name.pdf
```

The reason you may have had an issue is that, if your source file starts with a `-`, then `mv` tries to parse it as an option. Passing a `--` before your arguments usually helps (also with commands other than `mv`)

Or as suggested in comments:

```
mv ./-Cadence\ NDA\ Extension-\ Signed\ 10.2.17.pdf some-other-name.pdf
```

Prefixing your file with a relative (or absolute) path can help get around that issue.

Comment: Additionally, instead of escaping the spaces, you could quote the filename.